# File reading and Manipulation

Tags: c++, file

I have a text file:

```
1
2
3
stop
4
```

The code has to add each number to the previous number to get a new value and it needs to stop when it reads the "stop" in the file.

For example output would be:

```
1
3
5
Reading has stopped
```

How can I break the code for my output to be like this? 
The "reading has stopped", only has to appear when there is a 'stop' in the file. otherwise the output should just be numbers.

Comment: You should try to write something that should work and ask a question if you can't make that code work. [How to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You can read each piece of the file into a string and end if the input is "stop". If the input isn't "stop" you can convert it to an int using std::stoi

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main() {
    std::string numberString;
    std::ifstream file{ "filename.txt" };

    int previousNumber = 0;
    while (file >> numberString)
    {
        if(numberString == "stop")
        {
            break;
        }
        try {
            int number = std::stoi(numberString);
            std::cout << (number + previousNumber) << " ";
            previousNumber = number;
        } catch(...) {
            std::cout << "invalid number" << std::endl;
        }
    }
    file.close();
    std::cout << "Reading has stopped" << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your text file has only one string "stop", then there's a very easy solution: you just keep reading integers until the reading fails

```cpp
int main() {
    ifstream ifs("test.txt");

    int first = 0;
    int second;
    while (ifs >> second) {
        cout << first + second << ' ';
        first = second;
    }

    cout << "Reading has stopped" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The problem with this solution is that if you have other strings in the text file and you want to handle them in a different way, this solution will fail.

Hope it helps.